# Connecting to AzureAd through OpenID Connect seems broken in .NET 8

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, .net-8.0

I just upgraded my project from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and OpenID Connect to AzureAD stopped working. The following code works in .NET 7:

```
authenticationBuilder.AddOpenIdConnect(authenticationScheme: "AzureAd", displayName: "Azure Active Directory", options =>
{
              string oidcInstance = configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]!;
              string oidcDomain = configuration["AzureAd:Domain"]!;
              string oidcClientId = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]!;
              string oidcTenantId = configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]!;
              string oidcClientSecret = configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"]!;

              options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{oidcTenantId}/v2.0/";
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
              options.ClientId = oidcClientId;
              options.ClientSecret = oidcClientSecret;
              options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
              options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.GetAadIssuerValidator(oidcInstance).Validate;
              options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
              options.MapInboundClaims = false;
              options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
              options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");
              options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-callback-oidc");
              options.RemoteSignOutPath = new PathString("/signout-oidc");

              //Setting the following has no effect.
              //options.MetadataAddress = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{oidcTenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";

              options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = async userInformationReceivedContext =>
              {
                             //...
              };
});
```

I get the following error in .NET 8:

> IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from:
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
> HttpResponseMessage: 'StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request',
> Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent,
> Headers:
>
> {
>
> Cache-Control: private
>
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
>
> P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
>
> x-ms-request-id: 4379b336-fe23-4d6c-95c6-d71717573e00
>
> x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.16790.7 - SCUS ProdSlices
>
> X-XSS-Protection: 0
>
> Set-Cookie: fpc=Av3iPXMPIHBMgE-fomXi7KM; expires=Sun, 17-Dec-2023
> 02:58:22 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
>
> Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; path=/; secure; httponly
>
> Date: Fri, 17 Nov 2023 02:58:21 GMT
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Length: 649
>
> }', HttpResponseMessage.Content:
> '{"error":"invalid_tenant","error_description":"AADSTS90002: Tenant
> 'v2.0' not found. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID
> and are signing into the correct cloud. Check with your subscription
> administrator, this may happen if there are no active subscriptions
> for the tenant. Trace ID: 4379b336-fe23-4d6c-95c6-d71717573e00
> Correlation ID: 0c5cf6f7-311f-4122-a547-aaee24d3159e Timestamp:
> 2023-11-17 02:58:22Z","error_codes":[90002],"timestamp":"2023-11-17
> 02:58:22Z","trace_id":"4379b336-fe23-4d6c-95c6-d71717573e00","correlation_id":"0c5cf6f7-311f-4122-a547-aaee24d3159e","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=90002"}'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'." Does that url actually contain your tenant Id or was that a typo/censor?

Comment: I did not modify the error message. So my guess is that tenant ID is not sent to the server.

Comment: Are you getting the issue locally or in Azure ?

Comment: The project has not been deployed yet. So the error is happening in Visual Studio on a local dev machine.

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version you are using?

Comment: Do you want to continue with the same code with changes or any other working code is fine ?

Comment: Instead of adding all the configuration, directly call this line of code `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
`

Comment: Using VS 17.8.0. Ideally I would like to continue to use existing code because it took a long time to get other dependent code working like switching to other Open ID Connect  providers and for issuing and validating tokens. But I would like to see what you have in mind.

Comment: From your error it is clear that `Tenant 'v2.0' not found`.My [URL](https://i.imgur.com/koSlTfC.png)

Comment: Instead of calling all the each client secret seperately, retrieve the complete section of `AzureAd` as mentioned above.

Comment: If possible try to share the code repo by masking your client secrets.Will try to run from my end.

Comment: Thank you Harshitha. Will do. It's a large project so will take time to strip it out to the essential code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255963/discussion-between-harshitha-and-sandy).

Comment: Can you please share your complete `Program.cs` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to work with your code, even I got the similar error codes like you.

```cs
IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from:
InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
```

- The issue seems to be with passing the `TokenValidationParameters`.
- Removed the below lines of code

```cs
options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.GetAadIssuerValidator(oidcInstance).Validate; 
options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
```

- And added `TokenValidationParameters` as below.

```cs
  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
      NameClaimType = "name"    
  };
```

- Now Iam able to access the app without any issues.

***My complete `Program.cs` file :***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Validators;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        string oidcInstance = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]!;
        string oidcDomain = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Domain"]!;
        string oidcClientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]!;
        string oidcTenantId = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]!;
        string oidcClientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"]!;

        options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{oidcTenantId}/v2.0/";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ClientId = oidcClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = oidcClientSecret;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        //options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.GetAadIssuerValidator(oidcInstance).Validate;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
        };

        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.MapInboundClaims = false;
        //options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-callback-oidc");
        options.RemoteSignOutPath = new PathString("/signout-oidc");

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

***Output:***
[image]

Comment: That fixed the problem for me too. Thank you!!! Do you know what the removed line of code does - what functionality am I losing? options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.GetAadIssuerValidator(oidcInstance).Validate;

Comment: Do not worry about the removed lines.I have just changed the way of calling TokenValidationParameters.Comment that line of code which I suggested.You can see that the name is missing beside hello ..after login.

Comment: It sets the value for name.